# What other DIY solutions might be better than mask and face shield for medical staff to prevent being infected?

Tags: coronavirus, ppe, infection-control

### Coronavirus: Hong Kong doctor who monitored travellers at airport among 39 new Covid-19 cases

> Doctor’s infection prompts health authorities to review guidelines on protective gear for medical staff working at airport
>
> The doctor did not have on full-body protective gear, wearing only basic items such as masks, face shields and gloves. She had worked at the airport since Monday last week and had no recent travel history. She had dined with a colleague, a doctor, who had developed symptoms of the coronavirus.

So, it appears that they're not ruling out that the PPE she was provided was insufficient.  Certainly it's clear from China that patients are being treated with staff wearing full hazmat type protection and their own air supply.

Are there alternatives for medical workers where your hospital/workplace are not providing full PPE?

Comment: She dined with a colleague who developed symptoms, and presumably wore no PPE at all during that prolonged, close contact. Seems likely to me that she contracted it from him.

Comment: Not necessarily.  In many places dining together means being separated by perspex and on different tables but usually not facing each other.